# KItchen backsplash tile cut too short and grout line too thick

Tags: kitchens, tile

I just had my back splash installed in my kitchen and the tiler cut one section a bit too short. The grout went up today and the area is thicker then any other areas and very noticeable especially with a dark countertop. Unfortunately it is an area where there would be no appliance in front of it to hide.

Is there any way this can be fixed? Is it possible to remove the grout and put little pieces of tile in that section. I think that would be less noticeable then how it is right now. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also...I notice the tile is not as shiny as it was before the grout...do I have to wash it after the grout fully dries? I wanted to attach photos but they said to large to do so and I have no idea how to make smaller :)

Comment: Some photos might help. "*a bit too short*" is not a SI unit, so it's not clear how large the gap is without seeing it.

Comment: The dull haze is the cement in the grout mixture once the grout is dry you will be able to wipe it off. it is a good idea to seal grout in a kitchen to prevent or reduce staining.

Answer (score 2):

The only right way is to pop those tiles off and reinstall them with a better fit. Any attempt to conceal the poor workmanship will look tacky.

In my opinion, the installer should handle this for you. A cut end should always have a matching or smaller grout line for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Put up some sort of trim (quarter-round is canonical) to cover the gap.

Comment: What sort of trim are you referring to? Wood trim on a tile backsplash?

Comment: I think he was referring to 1/4 round tiles without a photo it is hard to guess what the correct path would be but 1/4 round sounds like a good idea to me.